# The code displays objects from one list, but does not display from another

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I want the "select" to list all students except those already recorded, but it appears as if the "students" list is empty.

```html
<ul type="none" th:each="discipline : ${disciplineList.disciplines}">
            <li><b th:onclick="|javascript:showDiv('${discipline.id}');|"
                   th:text="${discipline.name}"
                   class="discipline-name" style="cursor: pointer;"></b>
                <div th:id="${discipline.id}" style="display: none;">
                    <ul th:name="${discipline.name}" class="discipline-info"
                        th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(discipline.students)}">
                        <li th:each="student : ${discipline.students}"
                            th:text="${student.student}" class="studName"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="studOption" >
                        <select class="selStud" required >
                            <option th:each="student : ${students}"
                                    th:value="${student.id}"
                                    th:text="${student.student}">Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="add-student-to-disc" value="Добавить в дисциплину">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Now the source code of the page looks like this:

```html
<ul type="none">
            <li><b onclick="javascript:showDiv(&#39;7&#39;);"
                   class="discipline-name" style="cursor: pointer;">tyu</b>
                <div id="7" style="display: none;">
                    <ul name="tyu" class="discipline-info">
                        <li class="studName">hjk</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="studOption" >
                        <select class="selStud" required >

                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="add-student-to-disc" value="Добавить в дисциплину">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The same construction on another html displays all students:

```html
<div th:each="student: ${students}" class="student">
            <form class="student-form" method="post">
                <div th:text="${student.student}" class="student-name"></div>
                <input required th:attr="value=${student.student}" class="student-name-input" name="studentName">
                <input type="submit" class="btn add-student-btn remove-student-btn" value="Удалить">
            </form>
        </div>
```

If I copy the code above and put before or after the ul tag, it will not give me anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was simple. I have not added to my controller

```java
modelAndView.addObject(students, ...);
```